# vbscript comment code as single line not multiple line

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp-classic

```
<SCRIPT language="VBScript" RUNAT="Server">
    function f
        Dim rs
        Dim str
        Dim arr
    end function
</SCRIPT>
```

If I highlight the function, then click on Comment out selected lines button, or press Ctrl+K, Ctrl+C,  it comments the function as  HTML, like this:

```
<SCRIPT language="VBScript" RUNAT="Server">
<!--    function f
        Dim rs
        Dim str
        Dim arr
    end function-->
</SCRIPT>
```

How can I get it to comment it with quotes like this:

```
<SCRIPT language="VBScript" RUNAT="Server">
    'function f
    '    Dim rs
    '   Dim str
    '    Dim arr
    'end function
</SCRIPT>
```

Comment: +1 I like to know this too, but I very much suspect there isn't one.

Comment: It is possible in dreamweaver, but I am not sure about visual-studio-2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with Visual Studio.

Answer (score -3):

Well I've started a project in visual basic. Its a asp.net project. Here you can comment out the lines as you mentioned above.Start the project like below.
 Start VisualStudio2010-->File-->New Project-->VisualBasic-->Asp.Net Application

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<%  
    'Response.Write("ok")

    %>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

It has automatically commented out the line selecting comment out option

Comment: How does this help for _Classic ASP_?

Comment: Look, the question is irrelevant. So my question may seem to you more irrelevant. The question was unanswered before. I am just trying to answer the unanswered questions. That's it. There is nothing to vote something down unless you read the whole thing

Comment: vbscript is not vb.net, and the OP points out pretty clearly that the question pertains vbscript. a downvote is warranted - the answer does not address the question.